# Declare and initialize a Dictionary in Typescript

Tags: dictionary, initialization, typescript

Given the following code

```
interface IPerson {
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
}

var persons: { [id: string]: IPerson; } = {
   "p1": { firstName: "F1", lastName: "L1" },
   "p2": { firstName: "F2" }
};
```

Why isn't the initialization rejected? After all, the second object does not have the "lastName" property.

Comment: Note: this has since been fixed (not sure which exact TS version). I get these errors in VS, as you would expect:

`Index signatures are incompatible.`
    `Type '{ firstName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IPerson'.`
      `Property 'lastName' is missing in type '{ firstName: string; }'.`

Comment: Can you please update this post: the title doesn't align the with question and the accepted answer!

Comment: The concept which allows us to make something like a dictionary in typescript is refered to as "Indexable Types" in the official typescript handbook (see [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) ). Since it took me a while to find this out, I wanted to point everyone searching for the official documentation into the right direction by providing the "official name" for this feature.

Answer (score 455, accepted):

**Edit**: This has since been fixed in the latest TS versions. Quoting @Simon_Weaver's comment on the OP's post:

> Note: this has since been fixed (not sure which exact TS version). I
>   get these errors in VS, as you would expect: `Index signatures are
>   incompatible. Type '{ firstName: string; }' is not assignable to type
>   'IPerson'. Property 'lastName' is missing in type '{ firstName:
>   string; }'.`

---

Apparently this doesn't work when passing the initial data at declaration.
I guess this is a bug in TypeScript, so you should raise one at the project site.

You can make use of the typed dictionary by splitting your example up in declaration and initialization, like:

```
var persons: { [id: string] : IPerson; } = {};
persons["p1"] = { firstName: "F1", lastName: "L1" };
persons["p2"] = { firstName: "F2" }; // will result in an error
```

Comment: Why do you need the `id` symbol? It seems it is unnecessary.

Comment: Using the `id` symbol, you can declare what the type of the keys of the dictionary should be. With the declaration above, you couldn't do the following: `persons[1] = { firstName: 'F1', lastName: 'L1' }`

Comment: the `id` symbol can be named anything you like and was designed that way to make it easier to read code.  e.g.  `{ [username: string] : IPerson; }`

Comment: Do we need the semicolon after `IPerson` in the first line? It seems that I can compile without any error without that semicolon.

Comment: @DamnVegetables It can be omitted as the interface in this case only lists one property. When multiple properties are defined, they need to be delimited. Prior to v1.6 this had to be wuth a semicolon. Since v1.6 you can also choose to use a comma. I prefer using the semicolon as this is also the end-of-line delimiter, but the choice is purely personal. See this SO post for more background: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994253/why-is-the-separator-in-a-typescript-typememberlist-semicolon-as-opposed-to-comm

Answer (score 171):

For using dictionary object in typescript you can use interface as below:

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
    [Key: string]: T;
}
```

and, use this for your class property type.

```
export class SearchParameters {
    SearchFor: Dictionary<string> = {};
}
```

to use and initialize this class,

```
getUsers(): Observable<any> {
        var searchParams = new SearchParameters();
        searchParams.SearchFor['userId'] = '1';
        searchParams.SearchFor['userName'] = 'xyz';

        return this.http.post(searchParams, 'users/search')
            .map(res => {
                return res;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
    }
```

Answer (score 68):

I agree with thomaux that the initialization type checking error is a TypeScript bug. However, I still wanted to find a way to declare and initialize a Dictionary in a single statement with correct type checking. This implementation is longer, however it adds additional functionality such as a `containsKey(key: string)` and `remove(key: string)` method. I suspect that this could be simplified once generics are available in the 0.9 release.

First we declare the base Dictionary class and Interface. The interface is required for the indexer because classes cannot implement them.

```
interface IDictionary {
    add(key: string, value: any): void;
    remove(key: string): void;
    containsKey(key: string): bool;
    keys(): string[];
    values(): any[];
}

class Dictionary {

    _keys: string[] = new string[];
    _values: any[] = new any[];

    constructor(init: { key: string; value: any; }[]) {

        for (var x = 0; x < init.length; x++) {
            this[init[x].key] = init[x].value;
            this._keys.push(init[x].key);
            this._values.push(init[x].value);
        }
    }

    add(key: string, value: any) {
        this[key] = value;
        this._keys.push(key);
        this._values.push(value);
    }

    remove(key: string) {
        var index = this._keys.indexOf(key, 0);
        this._keys.splice(index, 1);
        this._values.splice(index, 1);

        delete this[key];
    }

    keys(): string[] {
        return this._keys;
    }

    values(): any[] {
        return this._values;
    }

    containsKey(key: string) {
        if (typeof this[key] === "undefined") {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    toLookup(): IDictionary {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now we declare the Person specific type and Dictionary/Dictionary interface. In the PersonDictionary note how we override `values()` and `toLookup()` to return the correct types.

```
interface IPerson {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

interface IPersonDictionary extends IDictionary {
    [index: string]: IPerson;
    values(): IPerson[];
}

class PersonDictionary extends Dictionary {
    constructor(init: { key: string; value: IPerson; }[]) {
        super(init);
    }

    values(): IPerson[]{
        return this._values;
    }

    toLookup(): IPersonDictionary {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And here is a simple initialization and usage example:

```
var persons = new PersonDictionary([
    { key: "p1", value: { firstName: "F1", lastName: "L2" } },
    { key: "p2", value: { firstName: "F2", lastName: "L2" } },
    { key: "p3", value: { firstName: "F3", lastName: "L3" } }
]).toLookup();


alert(persons["p1"].firstName + " " + persons["p1"].lastName);
// alert: F1 L2

persons.remove("p2");

if (!persons.containsKey("p2")) {
    alert("Key no longer exists");
    // alert: Key no longer exists
}

alert(persons.keys().join(", "));
// alert: p1, p3
```

Comment: Very helpful sample code. The "interface IDictionary" contains a small typo, as there is a reference to IPerson.

Comment: would be nice to implement element count as well

Comment: @dmck The declaration `containsKey(key: string): bool;` does not work with _TypeScript 1.5.0-beta_. It should be changed to `containsKey(key: string): boolean;`.

Comment: why dont you delcare generic type? Dictionary<T>, then no need to create the PersonDictionary class. You declare it like this : var persons = new Dictionary<IPerson>();

Comment: I have used such a generic dictionary effectively.  I found it here:http://fabiolandoni.ch/dictionary-in-typescript-based-on-arrays-of-generic-types/

Comment: wont this cause problems if someone adds the key names one of the dictionary method names 'Add'

Comment: should `class Dictionary` not be `class Dictionary implements IDictionary` instead? I think you forgot it, right?

Answer (score 31):

Typescript fails in your case because it expects all the fields to be present. Use **Record and Partial** utility types to solve it.

**`Record<string, Partial<IPerson>>`**

```
interface IPerson {
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
}

var persons: Record<string, Partial<IPerson>> = {
   "p1": { firstName: "F1", lastName: "L1" },
   "p2": { firstName: "F2" }
};
```

*Explanation.*

1. **Record** type creates a dictionary/hashmap.
2. **Partial** type says some of the fields may be missing.

*Alternate.*

If you wish to make last name optional you can append a ?  Typescript will know that it's optional.

```
lastName?: string;
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Answer (score 12):

Record<Tkey, Tobject> kinda works like a C# dictionary

```
let myRecord: Record<string, number> = {}; 

//Add
myRecord[”key1”] = 1;

//Remove
delete myRecord[”key1"];

//Loop
for (var key in myRecord) {
    var value = myRecord[key];
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a more general Dictionary implementation inspired by this from @dmck

```
    interface IDictionary<T> {
      add(key: string, value: T): void;
      remove(key: string): void;
      containsKey(key: string): boolean;
      keys(): string[];
      values(): T[];
    }

    class Dictionary<T> implements IDictionary<T> {

      _keys: string[] = [];
      _values: T[] = [];

      constructor(init?: { key: string; value: T; }[]) {
        if (init) {
          for (var x = 0; x < init.length; x++) {
            this[init[x].key] = init[x].value;
            this._keys.push(init[x].key);
            this._values.push(init[x].value);
          }
        }
      }

      add(key: string, value: T) {
        this[key] = value;
        this._keys.push(key);
        this._values.push(value);
      }

      remove(key: string) {
        var index = this._keys.indexOf(key, 0);
        this._keys.splice(index, 1);
        this._values.splice(index, 1);

        delete this[key];
      }

      keys(): string[] {
        return this._keys;
      }

      values(): T[] {
        return this._values;
      }

      containsKey(key: string) {
        if (typeof this[key] === "undefined") {
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      }

      toLookup(): IDictionary<T> {
        return this;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for an easy way to create a dictionary even in typescript, it is to use Map object. The link to the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map . Map object has the main methods of adding, retrieving and deleting and removing all elements.

```
dictionary= new Map<string, string>();
dictionary.set("key", "value");
dictionary.get("key");
dictionary.delete("key");
dictionary.clear(); //Removes all key-value pairs
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to ignore a property, mark it as optional by adding a question mark:

```
interface IPerson {
    firstName: string;
    lastName?: string;
}
```

Comment: The whole point of the question is why the given code compiled without providing a last name…