# Why is the separator in a TypeScript TypeMemberList semicolon as opposed to comma?

Tags: typescript, grammar, specifications

This is a typescript interface:

```
interface A {
    l: { x: string; y:number }
}
```

But this (similar thing) produces an error:

```
interface A {
    l: { x: string, y:number }
}

// => Error: ';' expected.
```

On p.37 of the spec:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf

I see that indeed it is specified that a `;` should appear there, but coming from JavaScript the semicolon in the middle of the object-literal-ish thing looks wrong.

Was this decision made to avoid ambiguity in the parser, or for some other reason?

Answer (score 116):

As of TypeScript 1.6 or so, you can now use either `,` or `;` as a delimiter in `interface` declarations or anonymous object types! The team decided that the flexibility to use one or the other outweighed the concerns listed in the 'old answer' section.

You'll still need to use `;` in class declarations to eliminate ambiguity:

```
x = 3;
class X {
  // Could be parsed as expression with comma operator,
  // or two declarations
  y = 1, x = 3;
}
```

I've retained the old answer below for historical context

---

### Old answer

Technically it could have gone either way, but there are many strong reasons to use semicolons.

In programming languages, it's more common to see semicolons marking the ends of *lines* and commas separating things *within* a line (there are a few exceptions to this, like enums). Most TypeScript types are large enough that they span multiple lines, which makes semicolon a better choice.

There's also a desire to have interfaces and classes appear similar. Consider something like this:

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
class MyPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
```

It's much easier to make `MyPoint` implement `Point` via copy-and-paste, or change something from an interface to a class or vice versa, if they use the same delimiter. Arguably you could have made commas be the delimiting character in class declarations, but it's a hard sell to be the first programming language in common use to do that.

It's also desirable to be able to tell object literals and type literals apart at a glance. While the single-member `{ x: string }` could be either depending on context, it's somewhat nicer if you can distinguish them based on their delimiter when the context isn't obvious in a complex expression.

Finally, every other language in common use with an `interface` syntax uses semicolons. When in doubt, follow convention, and the syntax for a type literal and an interface should *definitely* use the same delimiting character.

Comment: Honestly, would not expect question like this. But the answer make it really useful. Seem like you know what you are doing Ryan... ;)

Comment: @Ryan Cavanaugh - thanks for these thoughts. Do you work for MS on TypeScript?

Comment: Yep. I wasn't there for this particular decision, but have learned a lot about these kinds of things while working on the language.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh This appears to have changed recently to accept either semicolon OR comma. http://goo.gl/5fCp2R
When did this change? Can you update your answer? :)

Comment: Finally got around to updating this one

Comment: "Not expect a question like this", yet we're at +75 up-votes =P.

Comment: Some prefer semicolons, but in my team, we opt not to use semicolons in JS or TS; however, when you create an interface with two members and write it all on one line, a separator will be necessary. For this reason, we prefer to use commas and keep it consistent. My advice is that if you choose something other than a semicolon, have a reason that fits your team's preference, and use something for the reason I gave above, in a one liner they are needed.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh: can you update now that [separators are no longer necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994253/why-is-the-separator-in-a-typescript-typememberlist-semicolon-as-opposed-to-comm/77003781#77003781) if members are one per line?

Answer (score 4):

As of TypeScript 5.2.2, you can omit the separator altogether. This is correct:

```
type Circle = {
    x: number  // look ma, no comma or semicolon or anything
    y: number
    r: number
}

const c: Circle = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    r: 1
}

console.log(c);
```

[Live demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwglgJwMYBtoF4oG8BQV9QAeAXFAHYCuAtgEYQL4D0jUKA9mwNZRUCGANOTZQkbKnyhsGAZwhU4o9mUkNeZEMAAWcMgHM8BEKUq16B-AmPU6CHAF8cOUWWnARpeMjRRMuAkVIABn5zKCMoYNDLKABGe0dnaTY0ADp2XQAKJABKAG4cIA)

Comment: 7-year-ago me didn't even think of that one! Thanks for the update, valuable contribution here. (: