# Is there a semantic difference between delimiting with colon and semicolon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

While defining some types in a React project I noticed that my formatter wanted to delimit my type definitions with a semicolon, while I always normally use just a colon myself. Both work identically and compile without issue.

Is there any actual difference, and why are both valid?

How I normally delimit myself:

```
type RunDialogProps = {
  open: boolean,
  handleClose: any,
  dialogTitle: string,
  runables: Array<any>
};
```

With a semicolon:

```
type RunDialogProps = {
  open: boolean;
  handleClose: any;
  dialogTitle: string;
  runables: Array<any>
};
```

I was unable to find anything in the documentation that described the difference.

Comment: Thx for the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994253/why-is-the-separator-in-a-typescript-typememberlist-semicolon-as-opposed-to-comm. Partially since it is specific for interfaces. I imagine its the same argument for other use-cases, but still a bit curious.

Comment: `,` is a comma; `:` is a colon.