# Is it possible to declare and call a dictionary of functions in TypeScript?

Tags: function, dictionary, typescript, factory, enumeration

I'm doing a bit of refactoring and was wondering whether it's possible to declare and initialise a dictionary of factory functions, keyed on an enumerator, such that it can be used as a lookup for factory functions which can then be called? Or, alternatively, whether I'm going the wrong way about this and am missing a more elegant solution. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15879330/5387814) to declare and initialise a typed dictionary but I'm unsure as to whether I've declared the signature correct or not, such that the key is a number and the value is a function. I've simplified my code into a very generic example - I'm aware it's rather contrived but the intent is much clearer this way.

```
// Types are enumerated as I have several different lists of types which I'd like to
// implement as an array of enumerators
enum ElementType {
    TypeA,
    TypeB,
    TypeC
}

// Here, I'm trying to declare a dictionary where the key is a number and the value is a
// function
var ElementFactory: { [elementType: number]: () => {}; };

// Then I'm trying to declare these factory functions to return new objects
ElementFactory[ElementType.TypeA] = () => new ElementOfTypeA();
ElementFactory[ElementType.TypeB] = () => new ElementOfTypeB();
ElementFactory[ElementType.TypeC] = () => new ElementOfTypeC();

// And finally I'd like to be able to call this function like so such that they return
// instantiated objects as declared in the code block above
var a = ElementFactory[ElementType.TypeA]();
var b = ElementFactory[ElementType.TypeB]();
var c = ElementFactory[ElementType.TypeC]();
```

Comment: This is mostly correct, but in your type definition `() => {}` says "this is a function that takes zero parameters and returns a `{}`". You might want to change that return type to something more specific than `{}`, but note that you can't specify different return types for individual indices.

Comment: Thanks, @DCoder, I believe that's what I was missing! Could you put that in an answer and I'll mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct and this approach will work, but there's one thing that can be improved:

> ```
> // Here, I'm trying to declare a dictionary where the key is a number and the value is a
> // function
> var ElementFactory: { [elementType: number]: () => {}; };
> ```

In a type definition, `() => {}` means "a function that takes zero parameters and returns a `{}`". You can modify the return type here to be more specific, but unfortunately you will still need to manually express the type of the returned values whenever you call these factory functions. For example, you can do this:

```
type AnyElementType = ElementOfTypeA | ElementOfTypeB | ElementOfTypeC;

var ElementFactory: { [elementType: number]: () => AnyElementType; };

...

// this type declaration will not work
var a: ElementOfTypeA = ElementFactory[ElementType.TypeA]();

// but these will
var b = <ElementOfTypeB>ElementFactory[ElementType.TypeB]();
var c = ElementFactory[ElementType.TypeC]() as ElementOfTypeC;
```