# C# Dictionary in TypeScript?

Tags: dictionary, typescript

How should I implement TypeScript interface to define this C# models:

```
public class PageModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, FieldModel> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class FieldModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877362/declare-and-initialize-a-dictionary-in-typescript

Comment: Not a duplicate, that question is asking something different and much more specific: «Why isn't the initialization rejected? After all, the second object does not have the "lastName" property.»

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're looking for interfaces only then:

```
interface PageModel {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Fields: { [key: string]: FieldModel };
}

interface FieldModel {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Type: string;
    DataType: string;
    DefaultValue: string;
}
```

Some differences:

1. Javascript has no notion of long/integer/double, they are all numbers
2. In a simple map implementation which is based on the js object notation, the keys are only strings. In typescript these are called [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)
3. While you get use get/set inside classes, the interfaces don't have that and you can only define the property.

Comment: Why use an `interface` and not a `class`?

Comment: @fuzz If you're only looking for objects to contain data (without methods) then the javascript object is a better option than a class. You are using an interface to describe how this js object will look like.