# Angular 2 forEach for array of array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a json object response from serve as like below structure, I have to parse the data from this result.

```
[CGOLD-1: Array(6), CGOLD-2: Array(6), MGOLD-1: Array(6), MGOLD-2: Array(6), MGOLD-3: Array(6), …]
```

[image]

[image]

I have tried as like this to check,
My type script code,

```
baserates: Object = {};
oldbaserates: Object = {};
this.liverateservice.setcallback((data)=>{
this.baserates = data;
this.baserates.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item);
        //newArray.push(Object.assign({}, item));
    });
});
```

but my console not working this, I have to do clone object as like this

```
deepClone(oldArray: Object[]) {
    let newArray: any = [];
    oldArray.forEach((item) => {
      newArray.push(Object.assign({}, item));
    });
    return newArray;
  }
```

Could you please help anyone to process this type of data structure in angular 2.

Comment: what is the variable that you are using to store the value of the json response?

Comment: Please show us what the JSON looks like. I have no idea what that snippet at the beginning of your question is, but it sure doesn't look like an array.

Comment: It also doesn't look like you're using the `data` variable anywhere. Please show us a code example that clearly illustrates what you are trying to do. You've failed to explain what any of these variables are or what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have updated data structure again, Could you please check it again.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It looks like you have an array with property names. Is that what's being sent from the API you're calling? It's not even possible to represent that in JSON and it's not normal to have such a thing in JavaScript.

Comment: How do you even get that key-value pair array...?

Comment: Take a look at [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877362/declare-and-initialize-a-dictionary-in-typescript/15884066#15884066). You are trying to create a Dictionary

Comment: I need to deep clone my object to compare last and current values of the bid and ask rates to update color code. Can any one help how to do in this data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten an array of arrays with

```
const flatten = (array: any[][]) => (array ? array.reduce((output, array) => [...output, ...array], []) : array);

const flatArray = flatten(data);
```

Now the flatArray is just a single array.

You can see a demo of it here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wdtvs9