# Is there a way to search inside the ng For

Tags: angular

I have two arrays files and currentlyRunning.
Suppose the file is in index 0 and its progress is inside `currentlyRunning[1].progress` which is index 1
I am running the `ngFor` to show all files. Would this `ngIf` in the td work to fetch the correct progress because the index could be different but the file id is unique.

```
<tr *ngFor="let files of File; let index=i;">
  <td>
    {{file.name}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{file.id}}
  </td>
  <td *ngIf="file.id === currentlyRunning[i].id">
    {{currentlyRunning.progress}}
  </td>
<tr>
```

Comment: It would be better to create a dictionary / indexer and retrieve it that way. That would be more readable and also more performant.

Comment: See also [Declare and initialize a Dictionary in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15877362/1260204), the `currentlyRunning` would be the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in your component class and use it in your ngIf directive statement

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest otherwise, you should map the data to each other...

```
ngOnChages() {
  this.mapedData = currentlyRunning.reduce((map, file) => {
    map[file.id] = file;
    return map;
  }, {} as { [id: number]: iFile });
}
```

Then you would use in your template just simple lookup:

```
<tr *ngFor="let file of files; let index=i;">
  <td>
    {{file.name}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{file.id}}
  </td>
  <td *ngIf="mapedData[file.id] as currentlyRunning">
    {{currentlyRunning.progress}}
  </td>
<tr>
```

This way it is just O(n) complexity and you have a nice way to handle all of it